# How can I join my retopology into my sculpt model?

Tags: rigging, retopology

[image]I rigged my character and parented with my sculpted model, but my retopology didnt join with rig and did not move with armature.

Do i need to make topology and sculpt model into one object? if yes, then how?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Commonly, retopology is made on top of the sculpture and once is done, you  can just hide or delete your sculpture to start working with your new mesh

Comment: Brother, bones are not moving my topology then, it could only move sculpture.

Comment: What i was trying to say is that you should finish your new mesh (retopology) and then parent the bones to that new mesh... You need to unparent your bones from the sculpture and parent those to the new mesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to BSE,

The reason for doing a retopology of your sculpture is so you have a nice, clean model (with far fewer polygons than your sculpture).

It's this new, retopologised model that you want to rig with your armature.
The sculpture can be disregarded (or deleted), unless you want to use it to do something like creating a normal map.

For rigging, all you need is the armature and the low-poly (retopologised) model.

I've taken the .blend file that you provided in a comment.
I've provided an updated version here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6yutaho90x7w8s1/Puppy.blend?dl=0

The first thing I noticed is that your armature only has one bone. An armature must have multiple bones in order to deform a mesh. You can extrude  new bones by selecting an existing bone (while in edit mode), and pressing E.

There were also some issues with your model that needed to be cleaned up before parenting to an armature.

I noticed there was something strange about the scaling of your object:

[image]

**Note the scale is a negative number, but also the actual Y & Z dimensions are enormous, indicating there are some vertices elsewhere belonging to the model.**

To fix this, I took the following steps:

1. Delete the current armature.
2. Select Puppy model and press CTRL+A to apply the scale.
3. In edit mode, select half of the puppy (using 'L' key). Invert selection (CTRL+I) and delete everything else, leaving only half of the puppy model.

[image]

4. Reset origin point of object to center of Puppy model:

- To do this, I selected some vertices from the very centre of the model (in top-view), placed my cursor on these verts using Shift+S, then in object mode, right click and select Set Origin to Cursor. This is important for the next step.

[image]

5. Add a mirror modifier as follows:

[image]

6. Apply the mirror modifier by hovering over it and pressing CTRL+A
7. In edit mode, press A to select all, then M to remove duplicate vertices (your model has several which will cause issues when parenting to armature).
8. Use Shift+N to recalculate normals outside (to fix any potential issues with normals).

Now the model is ready to parent to an armature.

I took the following steps:

1. Place 3d cursor at Puppy origin (select puppy > Shift+S > Cursor to selected)
2. Add a new Armature (Single bone)
3. Tab into edit mode. Scale, move, extrude new bones as required
   NOTE: I've only added 4 bones as a demo. You will need to add many more.
4. Tab into Object mode.
5. Select **first** the puppy model, then Shift+select then armature.
6. CRTL+P > Armature Deform With Automatic Weights

Now when we move the armature in pose mode, the puppy model should deform correctly.

Comment: Sir I did same as u explained, but bone can not move my topology in pose mode, however it is moving in object mode

Comment: Would you be able to upload your .blend file (i.e on DropBox) and share a link to the file? I'll take a look and see if I can figure out the problem. Please delete everything except the sculpture, low-poly model and armature before sharing the file (to keep it small).

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u5w88ng9qsb14q5/Puppy.blend?dl=0

Comment: Thanks, just having some dinner then I'll take a look

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to a new file and an explanation of the steps that I took

Comment: Sir, you file worked and your answer is very helpful, thank you very much 

Comment: You're welcome :) Rigging is difficult at first but stick with it, it gets easier!

Answer (score 0):

You asked Blender to make the armature object deform your sculpted mesh object, so it does exactly that. There is no reason for Blender to deform an object that you didn't ask to deform. There is no reason to join objects together either.

If you want your retopologized mesh to be deformed by the armature, select that mesh, then the armature object, and hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> → whatever armature deform option you need.

People don't often deform a sculpted mesh with an armature, because sculpted meshes are often dense and heavy, it's harder to calculate deformations on them, and the result might not even e great because of how the sculpted topology isn't thought for deformation. That's one of the reasons why we retopologize meshes.
Hence, you should probably unparent your sculpted object too. Select it and hit <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.